# React list and item components listening to the store

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I've got a UserComponent that shows some user details. Using the React+Flux+Immutable architecture, I can tell this to listen for UserStore changes so it can update itself.

Now if I want to show a list of users, I may want to reuse this component and use it within a UserListComponent. This will also need to listen to the UserStore in order to add / remove items as they're added / removed from the backing store.

If I have a list of 100 users, this'll cause 101 components to be listening to the UserStore, and arguably 100 of those (the items) don't need to be because the list is doing so on their behalf. Is there an approach I should be taking to design around this situation? Or is it not something I need to worry about?

I'm still very new to React, and the samples I've been following don't account for this - the TodoMVC for example has TodoItems that don't listen to the store, and rely on the list to do so on their behalf. However, this prevents them being used outside of a list which seems a bit limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put state in a common ancestor/owner component (your list), and each sub-component (user detail component) will derive/borrow its state from that common ancestor -- as a `prop`.
For good performance, you can use Immutable in concert with the `componentShouldUpdate` function.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using Immutables. I'm not sure I follow the rest of your reply. If I wanted my UserComponent to function as a standalone component that shows a user (e.g. <UserInfo user={user} />) and keep it up to date, then I need that component to hook into the store events, right? Likewise, if I want a list of them then my UserListComponent will need to listen to in order to add or remove items - however this also has the side-effect of meaning I don't need my UserInfoComponent to be actively listening any more as the list will do it for me.

Comment: Is this something I could enable / disable as a prop? e.g. <UserInfo listen={false} /> in my list, or <UserInfo listen={true} /> for a standlone? Not sure if that's a good approach or not...

Comment: Short answer: No, Your UserComponent needn't hook into the store events if its parent (the List) is the one maintaining state.  View is changed by `React.render` runs, which are triggered by state changes; props are propagated and views calculated anew.

Comment: Having a component that functions under the context of a list and also functions standalone is another issue.  You might just make two components... it's an optimisation problem (reducing the amount of code transferred), and without seeing more of your particular use-case I wouldn't guess the best way.

Comment: Also, in the standalone case, you could put the state in a container component over the standalone userComponent -- whatever is most appropriate to your situation.  I assume that even in standalone case it's owned by something.  That something would be likely candidate for owning state.  The React docs repeat in various places the importance of deciding who/what should own state-- there is associated a more general CS wisdom which is that data-structures are more important than algorithms.